# Error while making ynot (library for Coq) in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, coq

I am trying to install - a library for the Coq proof assistant ( http://ynot.cs.harvard.edu/ ), which I am getting from here: https://github.com/Ptival/ynot (as I believe it is fixed for 8.4pl2)

I have:
The Coq Proof Assistant, version 8.4pl3 (January 2014)
compiled on Jan 19 2014 23:14:16 with OCaml 4.01.0

First, I git clone ynot to /tmp, then go there and issue make.

It breaks at STsep.v file:

```
> coqc -R . Ynot  -q  -I .    STsep 
> File "./STsep.v", line 191, characters 4-11: 
> Error: No such unproven subgoal 
> make[2]: *** [STsep.vo] Error 1
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You could either use an older version of coq (8.3 is available via opam) or port the library to 8.4pl2 and send the patch upstream.

Comment: It worked on Ubuntu 12.04, where suitable coq version was found, after installing camlp. Do you bother to write and answer, so I can acknowledge? Thanks!